# Safely opening a single QDialog inside a plugin of a non-Qt host application

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I want to open a modal `QDialog` to query some parameters for a plugin inside a non-Qt host application. I managed to do exactly that quite easily (for a `QFileDialog`) using the following code inside the scope of the plugin function that requests the parameters:

```
// code to initialize dummy argc and argv
QApplication app( argc, argv );
QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
```

Now, while this does open the file dialog just fine, there are a number of problems/errors.

The first time I call this I get the following error:

> qt.qpa.windows:
> setProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2)
> failed: COM error 0x5  (Access is denied.)

On all consecutive calls I get the following errors:

> QApplication::regClass: Registering window class 'Qt632ScreenChangeObserverWindow' failed. (Class already exists.)

But most importantly, the dialog is not "modal". In fact, when I click on the host application window, I can not even bring the file dialog in front of it again if I wanted to.

As an additional info: I do have access to a HWND handle that I can convert to a `QWindow` using `QWindow::fromWinId( hwnd )`.

Any hint on how to do this properly?

Comment: I'm just guessing but you might want to try setting [`QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) to see if that helps at all.

Comment: While `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` changes the appearance of the dialog to a more "oldschoool" look, it does not solve any of the the problems I'm experiencing.

Comment: "setProcessDpiAwarenessContext…… error 0x5 (Access is denied.)" If the default API awareness mode for the process has already been set (via a previous API call or within the application manifest), you will get the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` error.

"Registering …… (Class already exists.)" As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't register the class again. Destroying the window does not unregister the class.

Comment: As I have no control over the loading/unloading of the plugin dll, I can not keep the `QApplication`-instance alive as a global variable. So one part of the original question would be: How do I safely construct and destroy a temporary `QApplication` object inside a non-Qt host application? As to the second error message: Calling the system function `UnregisterClass( ... )` before destructing the `QApplication` object did not work, but crashed the host application.

Comment: what os? Windows 10?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unregisterclassa?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2

Also known as Per Monitor v2. An advancement over the original per-monitor DPI awareness mode, which enables applications to access new DPI-related scaling behaviors on a per top-level window basis.
Per Monitor v2 was made available in the Creators Update of Windows 10, and is not available on earlier versions of the operating system.

Comment: @VahagnAvagyan Yes, on Windows 10. The problem seems to be, that the existing window system did initialize said property and starting a `QApplication`, being unaware of the exiting windows, tries again. I guess the solution to all of the problems would be to let Qt know, that it is being run inside an existing GUI application, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: The first warning has been fixed in 6.4: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/19857fda75d049e64e39ff353d7f5ed3bd342d61

Comment: As for modality issue, you can try to create a dummy `QWinWidget` , and use it as a parent for `QFileDialog`.

Comment: @Osyotr Took me some time to get `QWinWidget` running with `Qt6`. Unfortunately I could not achieve modality using it either. The geometry in the `center()`-function does fit my host window, so the handle does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: @DrPepperJo check out this code. https://gist.github.com/Osyotr/63f66b2b7ac623d1732a2f1592cde664

Comment: @Osyotr Where do you get your `QWinWidget` implementation? The ones I found don't compile with `Qt6` (out of the box).

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that this was tested only with Qt5. The code was written by me a few years ago when we were migrating from MFC to Qt and is long since abandoned. Does Qt6 break it horribly? I've seen that somebody managed to port it to Qt6 https://github.com/ChaosInitiative/QtWinMigrate-Qt6

Comment: @Osyotr It was not a big deal to get it to compile. However, I could not manage to create a modal dialog as a child of `QWinWidget` and figured it might be because of some new `Qt6` features. But I guess it is more likely, that I did something wrong. I will do some more in-depth debugging.